# Why my Discord bot always sending win message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When i use this command, bot just saying **Slot oynarken **${kazanç} TL** kazandın!** what should i do or put to this code? I just wanna chance for lost but i always winning. My bot isn't saying **Slot oynarken **${argss} TL** kaybettin!** So i want win or lose. Help me please

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const { JsonDatabase} = require("wio.db");
const db = new JsonDatabase("./database.json");
const bt = require('best-tools')
const durum = ['kazandın','kaybettin']
exports.run = function(client, message, args) {

    var sonuç = durum[Math.floor(Math.random() * durum.length)];
    if (sonuç) {
      let argss = args[0]
      if (sonuç = `kazandın`) {
        let argss = args[0]
        var kazanç = (bt.hesapla(Number(args[0]) * 2))
        let para = db.fetch(`para_${message.author.id}`)
        if(para == para) {var enginar = para}
        if(para == undefined) {var enginar = "0"}
        if(Number(args[0]) < para) {
          const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
          .setColor('BLURPLE')
          .setDescription(`Slot oynarken **${kazanç} TL** kazandın!`)
          .setFooter('Dedende kumarcıydı aslanım ;)')
          db.add(`para_${message.author.id}`, Number(args[0]))
        return message.channel.send(embed)}
        if(Number(args[0]) > para) {
          const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
          .setColor('BLURPLE')
          .setDescription(`Paran yok oynayamazsın!`)
          .setFooter('Para getir leyn..')
        return message.channel.send(embed)}
      if (sonuç = 'kaybettin') {
        let argss = args[0]
        let para = db.fetch(`para_${message.author.id}`)
        if(para == para) {var enginar = para}
        if(para == undefined) {var enginar = "0"}
        if(Number(args[0]) < para) {
          const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
          .setColor('BLURPLE')
          .setDescription(`Slot oynarken **${argss} TL** kaybettin!`)
          .setFooter('Dedende şanssızdı boşver :/')
          db.delete(`para_${message.author.id}`, Number(args[0]))
        return message.channel.send(embed)}
        if(Number(args[0]) > para) {
          const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
          .setColor('BLURPLE')
          .setDescription(`Paran yok oynayamazsın!`)
          .setFooter('Para getir leyn..')
        return message.channel.send(embed)}
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. ``if( sonuc = `kazandin`)`` will always pass.

Comment: From what I'm reading, I think `para` is a type of string. I would try to format `para` as a number.

Answer (score 0):

When you're checking if a value is equal to or is true/false you need to check using `==` or `===`. Using `=` will change a variables values instead of checking.

```js
const durum = ['kazandın','kaybettin']
exports.run = function(client, message, args) {

    var sonuç = durum[Math.floor(Math.random() * durum.length)];
    if (sonuç) {
        let argss = args[0]
        if (sonuç == `kazandın`) {
            let argss = args[0]
            var kazanç = (bt.hesapla(Number(args[0]) * 2))
            let para = db.fetch(`para_${message.author.id}`)
            if(para == para) {var enginar = para}
            if(para == undefined) {var enginar = "0"}
            if(Number(args[0]) < para) {
            const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
            .setColor('BLURPLE')
            .setDescription(`Slot oynarken **${kazanç} TL** kazandın!`)
            .setFooter('Dedende kumarcıydı aslanım ;)')
            db.add(`para_${message.author.id}`, Number(args[0]))
            return message.channel.send(embed)}
            if(Number(args[0]) > para) {
            const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
            .setColor('BLURPLE')
            .setDescription(`Paran yok oynayamazsın!`)
            .setFooter('Para getir leyn..')
            return message.channel.send(embed)}
        if (sonuç == 'kaybettin') {
            let argss = args[0]
            let para = db.fetch(`para_${message.author.id}`)
            if(para == para) {var enginar = para}
            if(para == undefined) {var enginar = "0"}
            if(Number(args[0]) < para) {
            const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
            .setColor('BLURPLE')
            .setDescription(`Slot oynarken **${argss} TL** kaybettin!`)
            .setFooter('Dedende şanssızdı boşver :/')
            db.delete(`para_${message.author.id}`, Number(args[0]))
            return message.channel.send(embed)}
            if(Number(args[0]) > para) {
            const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
            .setColor('BLURPLE')
            .setDescription(`Paran yok oynayamazsın!`)
            .setFooter('Para getir leyn..')
            return message.channel.send(embed)}
        }
        }
    }
```